# Crash when starting activity

Tags: android, android-activity, crash

i am coding an android app. The app begins at the main screen then click the button to go the activity. My code does not have any error and build fine. However launching the app and click the button result in a crash.

My Manifest.XML

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidbtcontrol">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".bluetoothconnect">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidbtcontrol.bluetoothconnect" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public void OnclickButtonListener(){
    button_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.androidbtcontrol.bluetoothconnect");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
         }
            }
```

bluetoothconnect.java

```
    public class bluetoothconnect extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate3(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetoothconnect);
    }
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> pairedDeviceArrayList;

    TextView textInfo, textStatus;
    ListView listViewPairedDevice;
    RelativeLayout inputPane;

    SeekBar barAnalogOut;

    ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> pairedDeviceAdapter;
    private UUID myUUID;
    private final String UUID_STRING_WELL_KNOWN_SPP =
            "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";

    ThreadConnectBTdevice myThreadConnectBTdevice;
    ThreadConnected myThreadConnected;


    protected void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        textStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
        listViewPairedDevice = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.pairedlist);

        inputPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputpane);

        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH)){
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "FEATURE_BLUETOOTH NOT support",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        //using the well-known SPP UUID
        myUUID = UUID.fromString(UUID_STRING_WELL_KNOWN_SPP);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Bluetooth is not supported on this hardware platform",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        String stInfo = bluetoothAdapter.getName() + "\n" +
                bluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
        textInfo.setText(stInfo);

        barAnalogOut = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.analogOut);
        barAnalogOut.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnAnalogOutChangeListener);

    }

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener OnAnalogOutChangeListener =
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    //will generate too much data sent!
                    //SendAnalogOut(progress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    SendAnalogOut(seekBar.getProgress());
                }
            };

    private final byte SYNC_BYTE = (byte) 0xAA;
    private final byte LENGTH_ANALOG = (byte) 3;
    private final byte CMD_ANALOG = (byte) 1;

    private void SendAnalogOut(int val){
        byte[] bytesToSend = {SYNC_BYTE, LENGTH_ANALOG, CMD_ANALOG, (byte) val};
        myThreadConnected.write(bytesToSend);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //Turn ON BlueTooth if it is OFF
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            pairedDeviceArrayList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                pairedDeviceArrayList.add(device);
            }

            pairedDeviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pairedDeviceArrayList);
            listViewPairedDevice.setAdapter(pairedDeviceAdapter);

            listViewPairedDevice.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    BluetoothDevice device =
                            (BluetoothDevice) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(bluetoothconnect.this,
                            "Name: " + device.getName() + "\n"
                                    + "Address: " + device.getAddress() + "\n"
                                    + "BondState: " + device.getBondState() + "\n"
                                    + "BluetoothClass: " + device.getBluetoothClass() + "\n"
                                    + "Class: " + device.getClass(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    textStatus.setText("start ThreadConnectBTdevice");
                    myThreadConnectBTdevice = new ThreadConnectBTdevice(device);
                    myThreadConnectBTdevice.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(myThreadConnectBTdevice!=null){
            myThreadConnectBTdevice.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                setup();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "BlueTooth NOT enabled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    //Called in ThreadConnectBTdevice once connect successed
    //to start ThreadConnected
    private void startThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket){

        myThreadConnected = new ThreadConnected(socket);
        myThreadConnected.start();
    }

    /*
    ThreadConnectBTdevice:
    Background Thread to handle BlueTooth connecting
    */
    private class ThreadConnectBTdevice extends Thread {

        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;


        private ThreadConnectBTdevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            bluetoothDevice = device;

            try {
                bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                textStatus.setText("bluetoothSocket: \n" + bluetoothSocket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
            toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        SendAnalogOut( 0);
                        // The toggle is enabled
                    } else {
                        SendAnalogOut( 255);
                        // The toggle is disabled
                    }
                }
            });
            boolean success = false;
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                success = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                final String eMessage = e.getMessage();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textStatus.setText("Something wrong BluetoothSocket.connect(): \n" + eMessage);
                    }
                });

                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(success){
                //connect successful
                final String msgconnected = "Connect Successful:\n"
                        + "BluetoothSocket: " + bluetoothSocket + "\n"
                        + "BluetoothDevice: " + bluetoothDevice;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textStatus.setText(msgconnected);

                        listViewPairedDevice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        inputPane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }});

                startThreadConnected(bluetoothSocket);
            }else{
                //fail
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "close bluetoothSocket",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }    
    }

    /*
    ThreadConnected:
    Background Thread to handle Bluetooth data communication
    after connected
     */
    private class ThreadConnected extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket connectedBluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream connectedInputStream;
        private final OutputStream connectedOutputStream;

        public ThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            connectedBluetoothSocket = socket;
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;

            try {
                in = socket.getInputStream();
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            connectedInputStream = in;
            connectedOutputStream = out;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                    String strReceived = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    final String msgReceived = String.valueOf(bytes) +
                            " bytes received:\n"
                            + strReceived;

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textStatus.setText(msgReceived);

                        }});

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    final String msgConnectionLost = "Connection lost:\n"
                            + e.getMessage();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textStatus.setText(msgConnectionLost);
                        }});
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                connectedBluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="Please Choose "
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_bluetoothconnect"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidbtcontrol.bluetoothconnect">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/pairedlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputpane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/analogOut"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="99"
        android:progress="0"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some of the mistakes I can spot from the information you have given. Post the logcat exception details so that I can refine on this solution.

1) Don't use your own version of onCreate (in bluetoothactivity). An activity should have only one **onCreate** method. You also need to add the **@Override** prefix to the onCreate method. The code you have contains *onCreate2* and *onCreate3* methods which are erroneous. *That may be the reason for the crash, since when the bluetooth activity is called, it can't find the onCreate method.*

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   //Keep your bluetooth related functionality here.


}
```

2) When launching your intent, you need to specify the source and the destination too.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CallingActivity.this,CalledActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I fixed the crash by doing what you said. I was also calling the wrong layout in main. Not in the bluetooth functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your crash maybe caused due to your intent,in activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.androidbtcontrol.bluetoothconnect");
                startActivity(intent);
```

the right way

```
Intent intent=new Intent(firstactivity.this,secondactivity.class);
startactivity(intent);
```

you need to specify the destination